# SBT subproject test classpath mystery

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt

I am currently working with two SBT subprojects: `persistence` and `silhouette`, which `dependsOn persistence`. I am having a problem with the `silhouette` test classpath.

The `persistence` tests run fine. That subproject declares some classes in the `model.persistence` package. The `silhouette` subproject defines additional classes in the same package. Those additional classes are not resolved by other classes in the `silhouette` subproject when running tests.

Most of the errors are like:

```
Error:(7, 31) object routes is not a member of package controllers.silhouette
import controllers.silhouette.routes.{ ActivateAccountController => ActivateRoutes, SignInController => SignInRoutes }
Error:(18, 19) object silhouette is not a member of package views.html
import views.html.silhouette.{ emails => htmlEmail }
```

I can see the Twirl views and routes in the `silhouette` subproject are generated. They are not picked up by the `silhouette` subproject, which is weird.

Here are the SBT subproject definitions:

```
lazy val silhouette: Project = project.in(file("modules/silhouette"))
  .configure(webappConfiguration)
  .dependsOn(persistence)
  .aggregate(persistence)
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= silhouetteDependencies,
    javaOptions            += "-Dplay.http.router=silhouette.Routes",
    javaOptions in Runtime += "-Dconfig.file=../silhouette/conf/silhouette.application.conf",
    javaOptions in Test    += "-Dconfig.file=../silhouette/test/resources/test.silhouette.application.conf"
  )
addCommandAlias("testSilhouette", "; project silhouette; test")

lazy val persistence: Project = project.in(file("modules/persistence"))
  .configure(commonConfiguration)
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= persistenceDependencies,
    javaOptions in Runtime += "-Dconfig.file=../model/src/main/resources/persistence.application.conf",
    javaOptions in Test    += "-Dconfig.file=../model/src/test/resources/test.model.application.conf"
  )
```

[Here is a working project](https://github.com/mslinn/subProjectFail) that demonstrates the problem.

```
$ sbt ";project persistence; test"  # works
$ sbt ";project silhouette; test"   # fails as described
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing wrong with the project definition was a missing dependency in the `silhouette` subproject. The error messages did not make that super clear until I tried to run SBT console on the problem subproject:

```
$ sbt
[info] Loading global plugins from /home/mslinn/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /var/work/blah/project
[info] Set current project to Blah (in build file:/var/work/blah/)
[Blah] $ project silhouette
[info] Set current project to silhouette (in build file:/var/work/blah/)
[silhouette] $ console
... compilation errors appeared here...
```